# Mock function that is inherited while using pytest.mark.parametrize

Tags: python, oop, mocking, pytest, python-unittest

I am new to unit testing. I created some classes to get from an API, deserialize it to JSON and input its values to a DB. All classes are working and I'm writing the unit tests right now. I have the following classes:

```
import requests


class GetResponse():

    def getDeserialize(self, url: str):
        
        ApiResponse = requests.get(f'{url}')
        
        toJson = ApiResponse.json()
        
        return toJson


class MercadoBitcoin(GetResponse):

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        #super().__init__()
        self.beginningOfUrl = 'https://www.mercadobitcoin.net/api'


    # This method is to get generally from the API
    def standardGet(self, coin: str, method: str):

        self.URL = f'{self.beginningOfUrl}/{coin}/{method}/'
        
        urlGet = super().getDeserialize(self.URL)

        return urlGet

    
    # This method is to get specifically from the API Day Summary
    def daySummary(self, year: int, month: int, day: int, coin: str):
        
        method = 'day-summary'

        self.URL = f'{self.beginningOfUrl}/{coin}/{method}/{year}/{month}/{day}'

        urlGet = super().getDeserialize(self.URL)

        return urlGet
```

I wrote this test:

```
class TestMercadoBitcoin():
    
    
    @pytest.mark.parametrize(
        "coin, method, expected",
        [
            ("BTC", "ticker", "https://www.mercadobitcoin.net/api/BTC/ticker/"),
            ("ETH", "ticker", "https://www.mercadobitcoin.net/api/ETH/ticker/")
        ]
    )
    def test_standardGet(self, coin, method, expected):
        
        actual = MercadoBitcoin()
        actual.standardGet(coin=coin, method=method)
        assert actual.URL == expected
```

**I only want to test if the URL is the same as expected**, not to run the request to the API. I tried these approaches for mockings and both didn't work:

```
    @patch(requests.get)
    @pytest.mark.parametrize(
        "coin, method, expected",
        [
            ("BTC", "ticker", "https://www.mercadobitcoin.net/api/BTC/ticker/"),
            ("ETH", "ticker", "https://www.mercadobitcoin.net/api/ETH/ticker/")
        ]
    )
    def test_standardGet(self, coin, method, expected, mock_requests):
        
        actual = MercadoBitcoin()
        actual.standardGet(coin=coin, method=method)
        assert actual.URL == expected


    @patch(super.getDeserialize)
    @pytest.mark.parametrize(
        "coin, method, expected",
        [
            ("BTC", "ticker", "https://www.mercadobitcoin.net/api/BTC/ticker/"),
            ("ETH", "ticker", "https://www.mercadobitcoin.net/api/ETH/ticker/")
        ]
    )
    def test_standardGet(self, coin, method, expected, mock_requests):
        
        actual = MercadoBitcoin()
        actual.standardGet(coin=coin, method=method)
        assert actual.URL == expected
```

Comment: So what is the exact error problem.

Comment: The `standardGet` is being called when the test is ran. I'd like to mock it so it doesn't call the API.